# Heroku & AWS - Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'

Tags: django, amazon-s3, heroku

Trying to push my code from github to Heroku after setting up S3 for statics. I am using Django.

I tried different solutions I found on here, but no success.

Here are the different things I did.

1. Removed `whitenoise` which apparently is incompatible with
   `django-storages`;
2. I also tested the following combowhich returned no error.

   python manage.py collectstatic

   python manage.py test

I did manage to push the code to heroku with `$ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1` but obviousy statics are not there.

Finally, a post suggested to run `heroku run 'bower install --config.interactive=false;grunt prep;python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'`, but this only results in an error message for me `C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file`.

Code wise, I have a file called `Settings`, in which I have `base.py`, `prod.py` and `dev.py`.

**base.py**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url
from decouple import config
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent



# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "crispy_forms",
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
    
    'django_extensions',
    'storages',
    
    'import_export',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'fontawesomefree',


]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
            'libraries' : {
                'staticfiles': 'django.templatetags.static', 
                }
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='sqlite:///db.sqlite3',conn_max_age=600)}


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 10240 # higher than the count of fields

#storing static files
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

django_heroku.settings(locals())

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [

]
```

**dev.py**

```
from .base import *

SECRET_KEY = XXX

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*' ]

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

**prod.py**

```
from .base import *
from decouple import config
import django_on_heroku 

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mysite.herokuapp.com', ]

# Amazon AWS S3 Settings
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME =   ('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'

AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS ={
    'CacheControl':'max-age=86400'
}

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False

AWS_HEADERS = {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'

STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/static/'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/media/'

# Heroku Logging

DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'MYAPP': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}

# Heroku Settings
django_on_heroku.settings(locals(), staticfiles=False)
del DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS']['sslmode']
```

**traceback**

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Using cached install of python-3.10.8
-----> Installing pip 22.2.2, setuptools 63.4.3 and wheel 0.37.1
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/tmp/build_a1a18ada/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
           main()
         File "/tmp/build_a1a18ada/manage.py", line 18, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
           self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
           self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
           output = self.handle(*args, **options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 209, in handle
           collected = self.collect()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 135, in collect
           handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 378, in copy_file
           self.storage.save(prefixed_path, source_file)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 57, in save
           name = self._save(name, content)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 457, in _save
           obj.upload_fileobj(content, ExtraArgs=params, Config=self._transfer_config)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 725, in object_upload_fileobj
           return self.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 636, in upload_fileobj
           return future.result()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 103, in result
           return self._coordinator.result()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 266, in result
           raise self._exception
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 139, in __call__
           return self._execute_main(kwargs)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 162, in _execute_main
           return_value = self._main(**kwargs)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/upload.py", line 758, in _main
           client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Body=body, **extra_args)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 507, in _api_call
           return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 943, in _make_api_call
           raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
       botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchBucket: An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the PutObject operation: The specified bucket does not exist
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: "The specified bucket does not exist". Are you sure you're pointing at the right bucket? And that your credentials are correct? It looks like you're pulling those in from the environment. Have you set the relevant config vars?

Comment: Hi Chris, I checked and all seems fine. Prod.py points to `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME =   ('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')` and `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME` in heroku points to the same name as the bucket name in AWS. Is there a command that could help me make sure that Heroku reads it the same way as my eyes do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved my problem.

in my case I just forgot `config` in of `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME =   ('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')`.

Should have been `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')`.